# Schannel alerts are not being sent

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, iis, schannel

Can't get the SChannel alert messages to be sent to client while calling my WCF service.

I've enabled the verbose logging of the SChannel alerts to the Event Viewer by setting the "EventLogging" DWORD in the Registry Editor to 0x0004 instead of 0x0001.

My IIS server using an HTTPS binding using a valid certificate. I've configured my IIS SSL settings to Require SSL and Require client certificate.

The client is expected to receive one of the SChannel alerts at specific events, for example when using an invalid certificates such as bad_certificate, certificate_revoked, certificate_expired.
The current result is that the SChannel always succeed the connection, ignoring these validation. 
For example the below event is recorded when the client use a corrupt, expired, revoked certificates:
A TLS server handshake completed successfully. The negotiated cryptographic parameters are as follows.

[image: Event Viewer]

Comment: It turned out that it's a Microsoft’s IIS issue, where it violates the SSL protocol by failing to send a close_notify indicator before closing the connection as per [link](https://www.coursehero.com/file/p18k4d3k/Finally-the-eof-property-tells-you-in-this-case-somewhat-redundantly-since-you/) and [link](http://www.justskins.com/forums/23220-com-fgets-causes-50813.html) comment #16 and other sites.  I couldn't find a fix for this yet. Any help is appreciated.